# How do I search for a group of array values and return the array keys for those values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with two layers of keys as so:

```
$array[0][0] = 5;
$array[0][1] = 115;
$array[0][2] = 320;
$array[1][0] = 5;
$array[1][1] = 100;
$array[1][2] = 115;
```

How can I return the array keys (both of them), based on them having the same value. For example, I want to be able to return [0][0] and [1][0] because they have the same value 5 and then separately return [0][1] and [1][2] because they have the same value 115? I was trying this with the array_keys function, but couldn't really figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$array[0][0] = 5;
$array[0][1] = 115;
$array[0][2] = 320;
$array[1][0] = 5;
$array[1][1] = 100;
$array[1][2] = 115;

//Orginize the array
$tempValues = array();
foreach ( $array as $key1 => $value1 ) {
    foreach ( $value1 as $key2 => $value2 ) {
        if ( !isset( $tempValues[ $value2 ] ) ) $tempValues[ $value2 ] = array();
        $tempValues[ $value2 ][] = array( $key1, $key2 );
    }
}

//Check which has 2/more
$duplicateValues = array();
foreach ( $tempValues as $key => $tempValue ) {
    if ( count( $tempValue ) >= 2 ) $duplicateValues[ $key ] = $tempValue;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $duplicateValues );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 0
                )

        )

    [115] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

There 2 set of pairs

```
5 - [0][0] and [1][0]
115 - [0][1] and [1][2]
```